# Encoding inconsistency on /users/{id}/reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed

Take these two calls:

- http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/180784/reputation?todate=1278854265&pagesize=1

  `"title": "Save a custom ListView&#39;s instance state?",`
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/3222690

  `"title": "Save a custom ListView's instance state?"`

...and look at the `title` attribute on both. Spot the difference? :)

Comment: It would be nice to add the lines to your question.

Comment: @dennis - your clicker broken or sumpin? ;-) nice catch felix.

Comment: It might be relevant that the text in question is a member in two distinct structures.

Comment: @code heh, thanks for satisfying my lazyness and including the relevant bits of the json in the question :)

Comment: @felix, do you think your API should automatically return decoded Titles?

Comment: @jjn - I don't think Felix is asking for anything. I think Felix is raising 2 good points 1) consistency is a virtue. 2) the data is JSON, not html. If a character needs to be utf encoded, so be it, but html encoding is not appropriate for any field other than `body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.